# Symfony Webpack Encore advanced/custom configuration

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm thinking about using Webpack Encore in a new Symfony 5 project, I'd like to know if it possible to do the following:

1. Use symfony config parameters (for isntance from config/services.yaml or other yaml file) into webpack.config.js
2. Some users will define some CSS configuration (for instance text-size, some colors, etc...), internally these values will be stored in a database. Is it possible to read/use these values from database as values in LESS (or SASS) variables?

Thanks!